# What's the difference between `null == last` and `null eq last`, in Scala?

Tags: scala, equals

I see in the built-in class `MessageQueue.scala` of scala 2.7.7, around line 164, it's:

```
def extractFirst(p: Any => Boolean): MessageQueueElement = {
changeSize(-1) // assume size decreases by 1

val msg = if (null eq last) null
else {
    ...
  }
}
```

I don't understand `val msg = if (null eq last) null` well, why it uses `eq`, but not `null`. If I write `if (last==null) null`, is it correct? Is there any difference?

Comment: But to compare with `null`, is there any difference? Can I use `null==last` here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When either side of the `==` *is* `null` *or* if the first operand of `==` *evaluates to* null, then Scala will not invoke `equals`. So, in this case, yes, `x == null` is the same as `x eq null`; the `equals` method is *not* invoked. Pay attention to the cases below.

Consider this:

```
class X {
   // this is just for testing
   // any equals that returns true when the other object is null
   // is arguably broken. thus even though it may be invoked
   // the end semantics should remain the same
   override def equals(x: Any) = true
}
var x = new X()
x == null // false -- compiler optimization?
null == x // false
var y = null
y == x // false -- see documentation below, y is null, x is not
x == y // true  -- x does not evaluate to null, equals invokes
x eq y // false
```

And note that:

```
(new X()) == null
```

Results in a warning saying a "a fresh object" will never be equal (to null).

I suspect there may be slightly more/different code emitted for `x == y` than `x == null` (in case the equals must be invoked), but have not checked.

Happy coding.

---

Section 6.3 (The Null Value) of the Scala Language Specification has this to say:

> > The null value is of type scala.Null, and is thus compatible with every reference
> >     type. It denotes a reference value which refers to a special “null” object. This object
> >     implements methods in class scala.AnyRef as follows:
> >
> > - *[null] eq( x ) and [null] ==( x ) return true iff the argument x is also the “null” object.*
> > - ne( x ) and !=( x ) return true iff the argument x is not also the “null” object.
> > - isInstanceOf[T ] always returns false.
> > - asInstanceOf[T ] returns the “null” object itself if T conforms to
> >       scala.AnyRef, and throws a NullPointerException otherwise.
> >
> > A reference to any other member of the “null” object causes a
> >     NullPointerException to be thrown.

Comment: thank you. So, `val msg = if (null eq last) null` can be replaced with `val msg = if(null==last) null`, but not `val msg = if(last==null) null`, right?

Comment: @Freewind My testing indicates that `x == null` and `null == x` are both treated as `x eq null` and `null eq x`, respectively. (I believe as a compiler optimization). The only case that seems "out" is `x == y`, where x *does not* evaluate to null -- in that case (and only that case) the equals method is invoked. However, even if equals is *not invoked* when `x` evaluates to null in `x == y`, the compiler may not be able to generate as efficient bytecode as when `null` appears as one of the operands because it doesn't know that `x` will evaluate to null.

Comment: Thank you again! So, I can write both `val msg=if(null==last)null` and `val msg = if(last==null) null` for that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `==` in scala  is  different from Java's.

In scala, `==` is equivant to `equals` method in Any, `eq` is equivant to `==` in Java

BTW, why doesn't null.asInstanceOf[Int], null.asInstanceOf[Double], null.asInstanceOf[Boolean], null.asInstanceOf[Char] throw NullPointerException ?

Comment: "Approximately equivalent". See the cases in my answer that show the mapping isn't entirely 1-1. Consider posting a *new* question wrt. `asInstanceOf`. Since `Int` "does not conform to" `AnyRef`, I am not sure why it doesn't throw a NPE.

Comment: I have post a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285916/why-doesnt-null-asinstanceofint-throw-a-nullpointerexception