# why doesn't null.asInstanceOf[Int] throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception

Since Int "does not conform to" AnyRef,  I am not sure why it doesn't throw a NullPointerException according to [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) on Section  6.3 :

> asInstanceOf[T ] returns the “null” object itself if T conforms to
>   scala.AnyRef, and throws a NullPointerException otherwise

And neither does  `null.asInstanceOf[Double]`, `null.asInstanceOf[Boolean]`, `null.asInstanceOf[Char]` .

PS: My scala library is of version 2.9.0.1 and OS windows XP

Comment: I have to agree with you, the spec seems pretty clear. It should throw a `NullPointerException` or the spec should be updated.

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5236

Comment: Not an anser to your question, but you can use type ascription instead when using an object: `val x = null: String` or `null: java.lang.Boolean`.

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/pull/104

Answer (score 5):

In Scala `Null` is a type, which has a single value `null`. Since `null` is a value and every value in Scala is an object, you can call methods on it.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't agree with you. As the scala reference says, 
A reference to any other member of the “null” object causes a
NullPointerException to be thrown

Comment: Well this is exactly what happens. `null.toString` for example throws a NullPointerException. Exceptions are thrown at runtime. You can't do this in Java, because `null` is a language keyword there, so it won't compile.

Answer (score -1):

Indeed it is a bit surprising given the section 6.3 of the [language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) as indicated in the ticket by huynhjl.

The behaviour (`null.asInstanceOf[Int]` gives you `0`) on the other hand is somewhat consistent with the following observation:

```
new Array[AnyRef](3) // -> Array(null, null, null)
new Array[Int   ](3) // -> Array(0, 0, 0)
```

And as such may be useful in a generic class when you want to have 'a value' for type `X`, even if you don't have a particular value available. As in the second observation:

```
class X[A] {
  var value: A = _
}

new X[Int].value // -> 0 (even if X is not specialized in A, hmmm....)
```