# If an Int can't be null, what does null.asInstanceOf[Int] mean?

Tags: scala, null

As a test, I wrote this code:

```
object Ambig extends App {
  def f( x:Int    ) { println("Int"   ) }
  def f( x:String ) { println("String") }
  f( null.asInstanceOf[Int   ] )
  f( null.asInstanceOf[String] )
  f(null)
}
```

I was expecting to get an error on that last invocation of f(), saying that it was ambiguous.  The compiler accepted it, and produced this output:

```
Int
String
String
```

Now I'm guessing that this has to do with the fact that Int is not an AnyRef, so the only version of f that works for f(null) is f(x:String).  But then, if an Int can't be null, what does null.asInstanceOf[Int] mean?  The repl says it's of type Int:

```
scala> :type null.asInstanceOf[Int]
Int
```

but I don't really see how that works.  After all, if I try to cast a String to an Int, all hell breaks loose:

```
scala> "foo".asInstanceOf[Int]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(Unknown Source)
        ...
```

Of course that's to be expected -- "foo" can't be made into an Int.  But neither can null, so why does casting null to an Int work?  Presumably boxing in some form, but the type is still Int, which can't be null...

What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, and how might I have gotten further understanding this on my own, using the REPL or scalap or some magic compiler flag or ... ?

Comment: Another similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8285916/617996)...

Comment: Have a look at a recent spec update https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/pull/20 and issue https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4437, which explains some of the background story. It is a bit comparable to `default(T)` in C#, afaik.

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5176

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The behaviour of casting `null` to an `Int` depends on the context in which it is done.

First of all, if you cast a `null` to an `Int`, it actually means a boxed integer, whose value is `null`. If you put the expression in a context where the expected type is `Any` (which is translated to `Object` behind the scene, because in the JVM bytecode, there is no way to refer to a primitive type and a reference type with the same reference), then this value is not converted further - that is why `println(null.asInstanceOf[Int])` prints `null`.

However, if you use this same boxed integer value in a context where a primitive `Int` (Java `int`) is expected, it will be converted to a primitive, and `null` is (as a default value for reference types) converted to `0` (a default value for primitive types).

If a generic method does this cast, then, naturally, you get a `null` back.

However, if this method is specialized, then its return type is `Int` (which is a primitive integer in this case), so the `null: Any` value has to be converted to a primitive, as before.

Hence, running:

```
object Test extends App {
  println(null.asInstanceOf[Int])

  def printit(x: Int) = println(x)

  printit(null.asInstanceOf[Int])

  def nullint[T] = null.asInstanceOf[T]

  println(nullint[Int])

  def nullspecint[@specialized(Int) T] = null.asInstanceOf[T]

  println(nullspecint[Int])
}
```

produces:

```
null
0
null
0
```

Comment: I didn't realize Int is a primitive type

Answer (score 21):

Here's the thing: `asInstanceOf` doesn't have to make sense. What this method does is to tell the compiler to STOP MAKING SENSE, and trust what you are saying.

Now, if you want to know why it returns 0, that's because `asInstanceOf` works on `AnyRef`, not on `AnyVal`. When applied to an `AnyVal`, it will use the boxed version instead, and a boxed `null` has value 0.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it's just automatically converting it to zero:

```
scala> null.asInstanceOf[Int]
res0: Int = 0
```

And, of course, 0, unlike null, can be an `Int`.

Comment: Very interesting.  I'm embarrassed that while I asked the repl for the *type* of null.asInstanceOf[Int], it never occurred to me to ask for its *value*, which I foolishly assumed was null.  Thanks!  This conversion surprises me a bit, though -- hmmm.

Comment: It surprises me too.  I have no idea if it's the intended behavior, but it seems wrong to me.

Comment: This is the intended behavior--you get the same value from `var x: X = _` as you do from `var x = null.asInstanceOf[X]` for any `X`.

Answer (score 0):

First, we all agree that we cannot assign `null` to `scala.Int` as documented in http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Null

Second, why when we do `println(null.asInstanceOf[Int])`, it gives `null`?
This is because of the implementation of println. It eventually calls java `String.valueOf` method, which is

```
return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
```

If you do a `null.asInstanceOf[Int] == null` in the shell, it will return true, but it gives an opposite warning that "comparing values of types Int and Null using `==' will always yield false". I think this might be a problem in scala's type erasure.

Doing a `println` only needs a scala.Any type, so the casting of `null.asInstanceOf[Int]` actually has not happen yet. So we just need to remember that when you assign `null.asInstanceOf[Int]` to an Int, the cast happens at runtime based on Scala's erasure semantics, and it assigns 0 to it.

By the way, you can still do a f(null) without any compilation error because scala is doing an implicit conversion for you

```
 null -> java.lang.Integer -> scala.Int
```

However, you will see it blows up at run time.