# Casting null to Int and Double in Scala

Tags: scala, casting, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If an Int can't be null, what does null.asInstanceOf[Int] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749010/if-an-int-cant-be-null-what-does-null-asinstanceofint-mean)

I tried the following in REPL:

```
scala> null.asInstanceOf[Int]
res12: Int = 0

scala> null.asInstanceOf[Float]
res13: Float = 0.0

scala> null.asInstanceOf[Double]
res14: Double = 0.0
```

It would expect a runtime exception (`NPE` or `ClassCastException`) in that case.
Could anybody explain *why* Scala casts `null` to zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really strange, as it is not the behaviour expected according to the specification:

> `asInstanceOf[T]` returns the `null` object itself if `T` conforms to
>   `scala.AnyRef`, and throws a `NullPointerException` otherwise.
>
> -- [The Scala Language Specification, Version 2.9](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), p. 75.

And it's a [known bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1245) that is closed but related to [this one](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4437), which is open.

Comment: Ok, complete example `val x = null.asInstanceOf[String]`

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `null` is a reference type - casting always converts to another reference type - in this case the boxed version of `Int` or `Double`.

In the next step, the compiler converts the boxed object to a primitive value. If the boxed `Int` object is `null`, its corresponding default primitive value is `0`.

See: [If an Int can't be null, what does null.asInstanceOf[Int] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749010/if-an-int-cant-be-null-what-does-null-asinstanceofint-mean)

Comment: Thanks. Does it comply with the language specification ?

Comment: not sure about the part with converting between default values.

Comment: Yes, it looks like this part contradicts the specification (see answer of Nicolas)

Answer (score 1):

Those types all extend AnyVal, for which a value cannot be null by assignment, the reason why it turns them into zero in response to asInstanceOf however escapes me. It appears to only be doing this in the REPL however which is a slightly special case. In real code it returns null.

Comment: I did not try it in "real" code by myself but this is the behaviour my colleague noticed in "real" code.