# Inconsistent null equality check scala 2.11.7

Tags: scala, null, boxing, unboxing

Edit: This issue no longer exists in Scala 2.12.6

---

Original question (for Scala 2.11.7):

Why so strange warning?

```
scala> null.asInstanceOf[Double]
res0: Double = 0.0

scala> null.asInstanceOf[Double] == null
<console>:11: warning: comparing values of types 
      Double and Null using `==' will always yield !!!!false!!!!
       null.asInstanceOf[Double] == null
                                 ^
res1: Boolean = true //!!!!

scala> 0.0 == null
<console>:11: warning: comparing values of types Double and Null using `==' will always yield false
       0.0 == null
           ^
res2: Boolean = false

scala> null.asInstanceOf[Double] == 0.0
res6: Boolean = true

scala> val a = null.asInstanceOf[Double]
a: Double = 0.0

scala> a == null
<console>:12: warning: comparing values of types Double and Null using `==' will always yield false
       a == null
         ^
res7: Boolean = false
```

P.S. Same for `Int` and `Long`

P.S.2 It's not a duplicate - the problem here is that boxing doesn't happen at all regardless of `asInstanceOf` (as you can see from my answer) + the warning message is inconsistent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749010/if-an-int-cant-be-null-what-does-null-asinstanceofint-mean

Comment: Though I can't find anything in the spec that explicitly agrees with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This [issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9671) no longer exists in Scala 2.12.6. See [pull-request](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5176) with explanation.

---

Original answer (for Scala 2.11.7):

`null.asInstanceOf[Double] == null` compiles to the:

```
aconst_null
ifnonnull
```

The `val`-version compiles to the:

```
aconst_null
invokestatic unboxToDouble
putfield
aload_0
invokevirtual а
invokestatic boxToDouble
ifnonnull
```

So compiler just forgets to add unbox/box in the first case

Comment: I am from `Java` started recently with `Scala`, so this statement `null.asInstanceOf[Double]` does not make any sense to me. why on earth this is not a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @Vishrant Idk, does let's say Java's `Double a = (Double)null` give a `NullPointerException`? :)

Comment: No, it's not a NullPointerException, although value of `a` will be `null`

Comment: @Vishrant the whole issue I described is that scala is automatically boxing `null.asIn....` when it's part of assignment (probably for the sake of [unified typing](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/unified-types.html)), but forgets to do it otherwise (which is truly inconsistency for old 2.11.7 at least). In any case it shouldn't give runtime exception anyways.

Comment: Hmm, but the syntax is weird, calling something on `null` and that won't give `NullPointerExp`

Comment: @Vishrant And the whole `null` thing in Scala is just for interoperability with Java (and alike), thus a lots of bugs and inconsistencies. Recommended style in Scala is to avoid `null`s overall (by wrapping them with `Option`s).

Comment: @Vishrant `a.asInstanceOf[Type]` is equivalent to `(Type)a`. The reason it's that way is to make it stylistically inconvenient and avoid such conversions at all costs. Also probably to easily find those and "kill with fire" :)

Comment: Got it. That make sense then. Thx. :)

Comment: Your last statement also answer my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199570/scala-syntax-null-asinstanceofdouble-why-its-not-a-nullpointerexception

Comment: on low-level yes. They (quietly) do boxing/unboxing in order to easily return default value for the type. Basically absence of it (in certain cases) contradicts specification itself (maybe they fixed it already, Idk).

Comment: @Vishrant just for reference [this pull-request](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5176) fixed the issue two years ago. The absence of boxing/unboxing was caused by improper optimization.

Answer (score -2):

This happens because `scala.Double` == `double` in Java, which cannot contain a null value. If you want your desired behaviour you can use `java.lang.Double` this will be able to store a null value.

```
val n = null.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Double]
println("null? = " + n)
//null? = null
```

Another way to prevent the use of `double` is being more explicit about types

```
val n: AnyVal = null.asInstanceOf[Double]
println("null? = " + n)
//null? = null
```

To make things a bit more confusing try this:

```
println("null? = " + null.asInstanceOf[Double])
//null? = null
```

This shows the use of `double` will only happen when your null value is assigned to a val.

I do not have a good explanation for the compiler warning, this warning doesn't seem correct is this specific scenario.