# Why in Scala this statement is not a NullPointerException? null.asInstanceOf[Double]

Tags: scala

I am coming from `Java`, and trying to understand the following `Scala` syntax

```
null.asInstanceOf[Double]
```

Why is this not a NullPointerException?

I was trying to do something like:

```
var d : Double = 0
if(d == null)
    // do something
```

However, I got following error message:

```
comparing values of types Double and Null using `==' will always yield false
```

This got fixed when I changed `null` to `null.asInstanceOf[Double]` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587792/inconsistent-null-equality-check-scala-2-11-7#answer-35588386), but this is a weird statement for me, how on earth this is working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala's `scala.Double` does not correspond to Java's `java.lang.Double`. Scala's double inherits from `AnyVal`, the parent of all value types. It most closely corresponds to the primitive type `double` in Java, which can't be null. When you do `null.asInstanceOf[Double]`, you're actually getting the double value `0.0`, not a null double.

From the Scala language specification section 6.3

> [the null value] implements methods in scala.AnyRef as follows
>
> ...
>
> - asInstanceOf[T] returns the default value of type T

And the default value of `Double` is zero.

So, in short, your value can't possibly be null because it's like a Java primitive. So you don't need to do a null check in this case.