# Spark UDF not working with null values in Double field

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to write a spark UDF that replaces the null values of a Double field with 0.0. I'm using the Dataset API. Here's the UDF:

```
val coalesceToZero=udf((rate: Double) =>  if(Option(rate).isDefined) rate else 0.0)
```

This is based on the following function that I tested to be working fine:

```
def cz(value: Double): Double = if(Option(value).isDefined) value else 0.0

cz(null.asInstanceOf[Double])
cz: (value: Double)Double
res15: Double = 0.0
```

But when I use it in Spark in the following manner the UDF doesn't work.

```
myDS.filter($"rate".isNull)
    .select($"rate", coalesceToZero($"rate")).show

+----+---------+
|rate|UDF(rate)|
+----+---------+
|null|     null|
|null|     null|
|null|     null|
|null|     null|
|null|     null|
|null|     null|
+----+---------+
```

However the following works:

```
val coalesceToZero=udf((rate: Any) =>  if(rate == null) 0.0 else rate.asInstanceOf[Double])
```

So I was wondering if Spark has some special way of handling null Double values.

Comment: This looks like _DataFrame_ API, not _Dataset_ API - what's the type of `myDS`?

Comment: Its a big case class where the type of "rate" field is Double. I initialized the dataset by doing sourceDF.as[MyCaseClass]

Comment: See related issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12648 - a suggestion to allow UDFs with `Option[Double]` as input for nullable Double columns (and other primitives)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scala.Double` cannot be `null` and the function you use, seems to work only because:

```
scala> null.asInstanceOf[Double]
res2: Double = 0.0
```

(You can find excellent answers describing this behavior in [If an Int can't be null, what does null.asInstanceOf[Int] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10749010/6910411)).

If `myDS` is a statically typed dataset the right way is to use either use `Option[Double]`:

```
case class MyCaseClass(rate: Option[Double])
```

or `java.lang.Double`:

```
case class MyCaseClass(rate: java.lang.Double)
```

Either of these would allow you to handle `nulls` with statically typed API (not SQL / `DataFrame`) with the latter representation being favorable from the performance perspective.

In general, I'd recommend filling `NULLs` using SQL API:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{coalesce, lit}

myDS.withColumn("rate", coalesce($"rate", lit(0.0)))
```

or `DataFrameNaFunctions.fill`:

```
df.na.fill(0.0, Seq("rate"))
```

before you convert `Dataset[Row]` to `Dataset[MyCaseClass]`.