# Handling null values in Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as below.

```
Value1 Value2 Value3
30000  40000  50000
null   20000  10000
```

Also, I have a UDF created as

```
val testUDF=udf((a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) => {
   if(a==null && b!=null && c!=null)
       b+c
   else
       a+b+c
})
```

I have a code as below.

```
input.withColumn("checkNull", testUDF(col("value1"),col("value2"),col("value3"))).show
```

Resulting dataframe is as

```
Value1 Value2 Value3 checkNull
30000  40000  50000  120000
null   20000  10000   null
```

Here, instead of displaying 3000 for second row for the column "checkNUll", it displayed, null. Any thing I am doing wrong in my code?
I dont want to replace it with 0. Because, if I want to do multiplication instead of addition above, it will fail.

Comment: did you try "is null" and "is not null" instead?

Comment: Replace nulls with 0s and then add.

Comment: Yes. a.isNull throws an error saying isNull is not a member of Double

Comment: That's exactly what I was going for

Comment: Replacing zero will fail for multiplication. Updated my question to add that scenario too

Comment: You can't multiply with nulls there so that's a bummer. You need to find out in which condition you'd be multiplying and then replace accordingly.

Comment: Here are some explanations why you can't have null value in scala.Double https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285253/spark-udf-not-working-with-null-values-in-double-field

Comment: If the solution provided solves your problem, please accept it to close the issue as I see that none of your questions have been accepted.

Answer (score 2):

There is so many ways to do what you are trying to do and with the current information, I'd suggest using `coalesce` :

```
df.withColumn("x4", 
                   coalesce(
                        $"x1".cast("long") * $"x2" * $"x3", 
                        $"x2".cast("long") * $"x3", 
                        lit(0)
                   )
  ).show
+-----+-----+-----+--------------+
|   x1|   x2|   x3|            x4|
+-----+-----+-----+--------------+
|30000|40000|50000|60000000000000|
| null|20000|10000|     200000000|
+-----+-----+-----+--------------+
```

I'm casting to `long` due to this issue [Why do these two multiplication operations give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758338/why-do-these-two-multiplication-operations-give-different-results)

Here is another solution filling the column `x1` with 1 to multiply :

```
df.na.fill(1, Seq("x1")).withColumn("x4", $"x1".cast("long") * $"x2" * $"x3").show
```

It yields the same results.

One other option is to do the following :

```
df.withColumn("x4", 
                when($"x1".isNull and $"x2".isNotNull and $"x3".isNotNull, $"x2".cast("long") * $"x3")
                .otherwise($"x1".cast("long") * $"x2"* $"x3")
  ).show
```

I advice you to read the following entry about [Dealing with Null in Apache Spark](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/dealing-with-null-in-spark-cfdbb12f231e).

Comment: how would the first part result in `200000000`? Casting a `null` to `long` doesn't do anything, does it? Wouldn't you get a `0` in the second row because the first two parameters to `coalesce` would result in a `null`?

Comment: casting a null into long will yield a null thus the first expression is null. I'm sure of that.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was `$"x1"` in the second parameter as well. My bad.

Comment: No worries @philantrovert

Comment: Spark has a special NaN semantics which makes your UDF not working https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#nan-semantics

Answer (score 0):

You have to use filter in such condition because when value1 is null it wont call udf.

```
val testStr = """[{"Val1":1000, "Val2":2000, "Val3":4000},{"Val2":2000, "Val3":4000}]"""
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(testStr))
          val df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)

          val newdf = df.filter(df.col("Val1").isNotNull).withColumn("checkNull",df.col("Val1")+df.col("Val2")+df.col("Val3"))
            val newdfw2 = df.filter(df.col("Val1").isNull).withColumn("checkNull",df.col("Val2")+df.col("Val3"))
            val alldf = newdf.unionAll(newdfw2)
          alldf.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `na.fill(0.0)` to replace all `null` values as `0.0` and just use `+` notation to add the column values as

```
df.select($"Value1".cast(DoubleType), $"Value2".cast(DoubleType), $"Value3".cast(DoubleType))
    .na.fill(0.0)
    .withColumn("checkNull", $"Value1"+$"Value2"+$"Value3")
    .show(false)
```

Given dataframe as

```
+------+------+------+
|Value1|Value2|Value3|
+------+------+------+
|30000 |40000 |50000 |
|null  |20000 |10000 |
+------+------+------+
```

you should have output as

```
+-------+-------+-------+---------+
|Value1 |Value2 |Value3 |checkNull|
+-------+-------+-------+---------+
|30000.0|40000.0|50000.0|120000.0 |
|0.0    |20000.0|10000.0|30000.0  |
+-------+-------+-------+---------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: There is no way to modify my udf is it?

Comment: I guess you don't want better solutions, do you? :)