# Why is null converted to -1.0 in Spark Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following Dataframe :

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a",Some(1.0)),
  ("b",None),
  ("c",Some(3.0))
).toDF("id","x")

df.show()

+---+----+
| id|   x|
+---+----+
|  a| 1.0|
|  b|null|
|  c| 3.0|
+---+----+
```

Then I do

```
df.as[(String,Double)]
.collect
.foreach(println)

(a,1.0)
(b,-1.0) <-- why??
(c,3.0)
```

So the null is converted to -1.0, why is that? I expected that it will be mapped to 0.0. Interestingly, thats indeed the case if I do :

```
df
.select($"x")
.as[Double]
.collect
.foreach(println)

1.0
0.0
3.0
```

I'm aware that In my case mapping to `Option[Double]` or `java.lang.Double` is the way to go, but I would still be interested in understanding what spark does with non-nullable types such as `Double`.

I'm using Spark 2.1.1 with Scala 2.10.6 by the way

Comment: It was fixed in Spark 2.3.1. You can look at [this PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/20976)

Comment: Your second code snippet doen't even compile. I am using `Scala 2.12.6` version.

Comment: Related to [If an Int can't be null, what does null.asInstanceOf Int mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10749010/6910411)

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM spark does not work with scala 2.12.x

Comment: oh it is not...Really I am using Scala 2.11.8 version.

Comment: Spark will work with Scala 2.12.x from Spark 2.4.0. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14220 although the version is not even stable yet...