# Uninitialized variable (block cannot contain declarations)

Tags: scala, object, variables

Following [these examples](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-open-read-text-files-in-scala-cookbook-examples) and especially this code:

```
object Control {
  def using[A <: { def close(): Unit }, B](resource: A)(f: A => B): B =
    try {
      f(resource)
      } finally {
        resource.close()
    }
}

...

using(io.Source.fromFile("example.txt")) { source => { .....
```

I wanted to extend the `using` method so instead of a type which implements `close` it receives a string (filename), a function to open a source, and the processing function. In this way, I would avoid the exception which would be thrown in the above example in case the given file does not exist.

So I ended up with this code:

```
object Control
{
   def using[A <: { def close(): Unit }, B](opener: String => A)(name:String)(func: A => B): Unit =
   {
      var resource:A
                // ^ Error: 'Block cannot contain declarations'

      try
      {
         resource = opener(name)
         func(resource)
      }
      catch
      {
         case e: (_) => println(s"Failed to open resource '${name}' (${e})")
      }
      finally
      {
         println("Closing file ...")
         resource.close()
      }
   }
}
```

So I am defining a method, which takes as first parameter an `opener`-function, which receives a string, and returns an object which implements `close`, a string (for the opener function), and a processing function.

However it won't let me declare the `resource` variable outside of the `try-catch` block (so I can reach it in the `finally` block). It **will** work if I just put it into the `try` block like `var resource:A = opener(name)`, however then I cannot reach `resource` in the `finally` block.

How can I solve it? I have to say that I am still a beginner in Scala, so I am a bit lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a revised example that you can also run [on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/yJbWFVbcTS6urv2ccDGOgA):

```
import scala.util.control.NonFatal
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

type Resource = { def close(): Unit }

def using[A <: Resource, B](opener: String => A)(name: String)(func: A => B): Unit = {

  var resource = null.asInstanceOf[A]

  try {
     resource = opener(name)
     func(resource)
  } catch {
     case NonFatal(e) => println(s"Failed to open resource '${name}' (${e.getMessage})")
  } finally {
     println("Closing resource...")
     resource.close()
  }

}

final class SomeKindOfResource(n: String) {

  def use(): Int = n.toInt

  def close(): Unit = {}

}

using(new SomeKindOfResource(_))("42")(n => println(n.use()))
using(new SomeKindOfResource(_))("NaN")(n => println(n.use()))
```

The piece that you were lacking is that initialization:

```
var resource = null.asInstanceOf[A]
```

Please note that despite what you may think, this does not throw a `NullPointerException`. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285916/why-doesnt-null-asinstanceofint-throw-a-nullpointerexception).

I've added a few more things you may be interested in:

- explicitly importing `scala.language.reflectiveCalls`: structural typing is achieved at runtime through reflective calls (on the JVM, at least) and the compiler will tell you at compile time with a warning
- naming the `{ def close(): Unit }` to something that makes it a little bit more readable in the method signature using `type`
- using `NonFatal` to handle exception (you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29744462/the-difference-between-nonfatal-and-exception-in-scala))

Comment: Thanks, that made it work. I tried several variants of initialization (`var resource = null`) but none seemed to work. This one does :)

Comment: What is the difference between `case e: (_) =>` and `case NonFatal(e) =>`? And why does `case e:NonFatal =>` not work, but `case e:IOException =>` *does* work? Seriously, this language does not stop to confuse the fuck out of me, even after beeing a programmer for more than 12 years :D

Comment: `NonFatal` is not a type of exception. `NonFatal` is an extractor (https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html) that allows you to catch all non fatal exceptions. The answer I linked in my own goes more in depth.