# What is the difference between a.ne(null) and a != null in Scala?

Tags: scala, null

I have been always using

```
a != null
```

to check that `a` is not a null reference. But now I've met another way used:

```
a.ne(null)
```

what way is better and how are they different?

Comment: I don't know scala but in general it's not good to invoke a method on the object if you don't know if it's null or not. In many languages this will provoke a 'NullPointerException' .

Comment: @yoshi: this is not true in Scala, actually `null.eq(null)` is perfectly valid and returns `true` (`ne` stands for !(this eq that)`)

Comment: The other way round with a reference to your specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055299/whats-the-difference-between-null-last-and-null-eq-last-in-scala

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like @Jack said `x ne null` is equal to `!(x eq null)`. The difference between `x != null` and `x ne null` is that `!=` checks for value equality and `ne` checks for reference equality.

Example:

```
scala> case class Foo(x: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> Foo(2) != Foo(2)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> Foo(2) ne Foo(2)
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: So, in practice, when comparing with `null`, there's no difference, right?

Comment: There is a difference. `!=` can be overriden, `ne` can't. Also `ne` just checks for the reference, while `!=` might check for other things.

Comment: But it is still not clear for me practically: how should I check a String argument to be not null: with != or with ne?

Comment: If you check for `null`, I would suggest you to always use `ne`, because `null` is always the same reference and you only want to check for that.

Answer (score 6):

Besides that said @drexin and @Jack, `ne` defined in [AnyRef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.AnyRef) and exists only for referential types.

```
scala> "null".ne(null)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> 1.ne(null)
<console>:5: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: ?{val ne: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method int2Integer in object Predef of type (Int)java.lang.Integer
 and method intWrapper in object Predef of type (Int)scala.runtime.RichInt
 are possible conversion functions from Int to ?{val ne: ?}
       1.ne(null)

scala> 1 != null
res2: Boolean = true
```

Comment: "and exists only for referential types" do you mean there are value types in Scala?