# Is ne a better way to check null than !=?

Tags: scala

Looking at some scala 2.10.4 library code:

```
implicit def wrapIntArray(xs: Array[Int]): WrappedArray[Int] = if (xs ne null) new WrappedArray.ofInt(xs) else null
```

What are the issues in making it:

```
if (xs != null) new WrappedArray.ofInt(xs) else null
```

Comment: I don't think there is a difference in this case, but I am hesitant to use null in Scala - is there no way to rather use an Option?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066927/what-is-the-difference-between-a-nenull-and-a-null-in-scala

Comment: one more thing != is `not equals` while `ne` means `not ref`

Answer (score 3):

Ideally this should be written to avoid nulls altogether, e.g.

```
implicit def wrapIntArray(xs: Array[Int]): Option[WrappedArray[Int]] = 
  Option(xs).map(a => new WrappedArray.ofInt(xs))
```

However given that this is a library function, changing its signature might not be possible. We could still use the Option approach internally though:

```
implicit def wrapIntArray(xs: Array[Int]): WrappedArray[Int] = 
  Option(xs).map(a => new WrappedArray.ofInt(xs)).getOrElse(null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider writing this as:

```
implicit def wrapIntArray(xs: Array[Int]): Option[WrappedArray[Int]] = Option(xs).map(new WrappedArray.ofInt)
```

and work within the Option "context" (`Option(xs)` will be `None` if `xs` is `null`) rather than dealing with `null`.